# How do I wrap the label text of a checkbox with a span tag?

Tags: 7, forms

I have noticed that Drupal 7 generates check-boxes with a markup like this:

```
<label ..>
<input type="checkbox">
Label text ..
</label>
```

I want to wrap  `Label text ..` inside a span tag, how to do that via the Drupal 7 API?

The result should be:

```
<label ..>
<input type="checkbox">
<span>Label text ..</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either need to override `theme_form_element` in your theme, or, do a `hook_form_alter`, target specific checkbox form elements, and change their `#theme_wrappers` callback to your own theme implementation.

I personally would do the latter, since overriding `theme_form_element` will change the default rendering for any form element in your theme, and that may not be desirable in every scenario.

Comment: Thanks.. My issue was related to Bootstrap's theme, I simply copied `theme_form_element` and `theme_form_element_label` to my custom theme's `template.php` and that's is, issue solved and desired output obtained.